# Python Pandas Dataframe change cell value in loop not reflecting immediately

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df as follows:

**Regiment FinalScore**

nighthawks -1

dragoons   -1

scouts     -1

```
for index_p, row_p in df.iterrows():
  df.ix[index_p, 'finalScore'] += 1
  print(row_p['finalScore'])

print(df)
```

What I get is:

-1

-1

-1

**Regiment FinalScore**

nighthawks 0

dragoons   0

scouts     0

Why is it that while changing the value of 'FinalScore' in the loop I do not get the updated values printed? And why are the updated values only reflected after the loop?

thanks

Comment: Because the iterator makes a copy, which you are printing. It does not reflect changes to the dataframe at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataframe iterator returns a copy of the row, so you don't see your changes to the underlying row.

Reference: [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)